# How to setup ENGLISH as a default language for iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslocalizedstring, nslocale

I developed an application in **ITALIAN** for the first version. Everything was working fine ! Then when i wanted to do it Multi-language for the 2.0 Release i didn't manage to setup **ENGLISH** as a default language.

The Steps i did:

- Root Project --> Info --> Localizations --> Use Base Internalization

[image]

- Then i get this (English).strings file that i translated from italian to English

[image]

- I setup in info.plist "Localization native development region" to "en"...so as to get the english as default.

**MY GOAL**

I would like when a user device is set in **French** or any other language that is not (ENGLISH or ITALIAN)...it shows this final user the ENGLISH Version not the Italian.

PS: Let me remind you that my base version is in Italian

Answer (score -1):

You can edit it in the info configuration, the item "Localization native development region" change to english, if have no the item you need add one.

Comment: not your picture info, the TARGETS info plist file configuration.

Comment: Already done ! But I doesn't work ! When I set the device to English it work , same for Italian ...but when I setup it in French ... It shows me the Italian version

Comment: please also close and reopen your project, then CLEAN and BUILD.

Comment: are you sure? do you know my means?